# How to include more search items in iOS spotlight search

Tags: ios, xcode, search, bundle

I created a project, settings its name, say: ABCXYZ. When I use iOS Search app (swipe down in the main menu), type XYZ, my app doesn't appear.

What do I have to include in my XCode project in order to get more option in search? Like, type A, type X, they show my App. In case of ABC-XYZ also.

Additional, I want user can search our company name also. Like Company1, they search Company1 and show our company's apps (in this case is ABCXYZ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do much about it since the spotlight's search mechanism is built-in in iOS. When user types a keyword, iOS will search the following two names of all installed apps:

- The app's bundle display name (the name used in your home screen).
- The (usually) longer name used in the App Store.

When searching, iOS will do a case-insensitive match from the beginning of each "word" in the name. For example, if your app is called `ABCXYZ`, both `A`, `ABC` and `ABCX` will match the name, but not `XYZ`. However, it's worth pointing out that each "component" of the camel-case styled name will be treated as a different word. So if your app is named `AbcXyz`, keyword of `abc` and `xyz` will both match your app.

AFAIK there is no way to alter the search mechanism or add new keywords to your app. All you can do is to optimize the aforementioned two names that are used for searching. For example, you can include some relevant information in your "App Store name," but I wouldn't recommend to abuse it.

Comment: Thank you. What if in the case like ABC-XYZ, can my search for XYZ fullfill?

Comment: @Eddie Yes, `ABC-XYZ` will do.